# Not able to install extensions in Visual Studio Code (VSC)

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSC version is latest (1.79.2)
My computer has Windows 10

I have installed multiple times VSC in last 2 days, and every time I have the following error when opening VSC:  "[error] Error scanning user extensions: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 718"

No VSC extension is installed, since every time I try to install an VSC extension I am getting the error "[error] SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 718"

I have tried various solutions found on Internet, without success:

1. added Code.exe to Windows 10 Firewall
2. checked that my computer does not have proxies in the System (and User) Environment Variables
3. used same Settings.json file as another computer  on which VSC extensions can be installed
4. uninstalled and installed VSC on another computer, on which VSC extensions can be installed

I also opened an issue ticket on the VS Code GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185436.

Comment: have you removed the folder `c:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Code`

Comment: if it does not show which JSON it is parsing, you should create an issue so they update the error message

Comment: Yes, I have also removed the folder c:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Code. It did not solve my problem

Comment: You might try deleting the `extensions.json` file.  It can be found by using the command `Extensions: Open Extensions Folders`.  The `extensions.json` file will be recreated automatically by vscode when needed.  If deleting the ``extensions.json` file isn't enough, you can delete any extension folders found at the above location.  It sounds like you might have a problematic extension that is still hanging around.

Comment: I have removed the entire folder (indicated by  F1 > Open Extensions Folder), and this solved the problem.  @Mark, do you want to repost your comment as a possible solution, such that I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you can try in this case.

1. Run the command `Help: Start Extension Bisect` in case there is an extension still causing problems.  This can happen even in a re-install if there were extensions previously installed.
2. Run the command `Extensions: Open Extensions Folders` - this will show you where the extensions folder is located on your machine.

   a. In that folder, delete the `extensions.json` file.  It contains information about any previously installed extensions, even if they were later disabled.  If there are still enabled extensions this file will be re-created on a reload so it is okay to delete it.  There is a chance that on the re-creation of the `extensions.json` file that a problem in it will be fixed.

   b.  Delete the entire `extensions` folder you find after the `Extensions: Open Extensions Folders` command.  You will have to reinstall any extensions you want but that would give you an opportunity to see if one of them causes you to be unable to install any more.
3. Downgrade your version of vscode.  Go to [vscode updates](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_78) and choose which version you want to download.